# TextView taller than containing TableRow after calling spinner.setdapter() in same row

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-spinner, android-tablelayout

I have a xml view that I'm inflating. I'm then doing a network call and with the results populating all these spinners. This is what the view looks like before I call setadapter on the spinners.

[image: What View looks like before I call setadapter() on adjacent spinner]

However, when I call spinner.setadapter(), my last TextView gets cut off.
[image]

[image]

As you can see, the TextView is larger than the TableRow.
Here is snippet of xml layout.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
android:layout_marginRight="3dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bcast_table">

        <TableRow style="@style/row">
            <CheckBox style="@style/chbx"
                android:text="@string/title_num_retx"
                android:id="@+id/num_retx_chbx" />
            <Spinner style="@style/spinner"
                android:id="@+id/num_retx_spinner" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow style="@style/row">
            <CheckBox style="@style/chbx"
                android:text="@string/title_cwm0"
                android:id="@+id/cwm0_chbx" />
            <Spinner style="@style/spinner"
                android:id="@+id/cwm0_spinner" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is how I setadapter()

```
    static void populateSpinner(int spinId, ArrayList<String> fields, String currPos, View template, Context context){
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) template.findViewById(spinId);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fields);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    int position = adapter.getPosition(currPos);
    spinner.setSelection(position);
}
```

Thanks for the help!